# Android emulator does not not run - stuck at "starting up"

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image: Image of the problem]

The emulator does not run. I've tried deleting the default emulator and adding new emulators and also wiping their data. None of these resolve the issue.

Even VSCode shows multiple errors with error code: "The Android emulator exited with code -1073741819 during startup"

Please help!